# javascript code explanation

Tags: javascript, dojo, javascript-framework

Can someone explain to me what this code does?

```
dojo[(show ? "remove" : "add") + "Class"](this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");
```

Here's the function in which this function value belongs to:

```
// Provide the class
dojo.provide("tweetview._ViewMixin");
 
// Declare the class
dojo.declare("tweetview._ViewMixin", null, {
    // Returns this pane's list
    getListNode: function() {
        return this.getElements("tweetviewList",this.domNode)[0];
    },
    // Updates the list widget's state
    showListNode: function(show) {
        dojo[(show ? "remove" : "add") + "Class"](this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");
    },
    // Pushes data into a template - primitive
    substitute: function(template,obj) {
        return template.replace(/\$\{([^\s\:\}]+)(?:\:([^\s\:\}]+))?\}/g, function(match,key){
            return obj[key];
        });
    },
    // Get elements by CSS class name
    getElements: function(cssClass,rootNode) {
        return (rootNode || dojo.body()).getElementsByClassName(cssClass);
    }
});
```

Source: [http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/mobile/tweetview/starting_tweetview](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/mobile/tweetview/starting_tweetview/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite simple, if show is true, it will call `dojo.removeClass(this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");` and if its false, it will call `dojo.addClass(this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");`.
Essentially its a toggling function.

the [ ] brackets open up an object to access the value by key. just like `var bla={"foo":"bar"}; bla["foo"];`. Now, since its dojo, the value is a function, which will be executed

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got a down vote. One could argue that it's not so much if `show` is true, but more if `show` is a truthy value (i.e., not 0, "", false, null, undefined, or NaN), but that's a minor nitpick.

Comment: Thank you for upping my answer again. +1 for your information about true-thy values! But false, "", null, undefined, 0 and NaN are of course false and not true values! Guess you mixed it up :) and -10, 20, true, "foobar", an object, an array, functions are true values.

Comment: I started my list with the word "not" to imply that I mean any value except for those I listed. I would argue that I didn't mix it up, my 'not' just got missed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more verbosely, the code does something like this:

```
if (show) { f = dojo["removeClass"]; }
else      { f = dojo["addClass"];    }

f(this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");
```

I suppose `dojo` acts as a container for functions that can be looked up by name via `[]`.

Comment: Lookup of properties via bracket syntax isn't Dojo, that's just JS.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the `[]` brackets and the `?:` ternary operator, to do something like this:

```
if(show){
    dojo.removeClass(this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");
}else{
    dojo.addClass(this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It "toggles" the class via the "show" variable.  That is, if "show" is truthy, then the class will be removed from the node, otherwise it will be added to the node.

Consider using the following shortcut:

```
dojo.toggleClass(this.listNode, "tweetviewHidden", !show);
```